# How to change background of SWT ExpandBar

Tags: java, widget, swt, paint, graphicscontext

I have an rcp application that has expand bars in it, and while the default colors and backgrounds look good in Windows 7, my clients who use Windows XP have quite an ugly looking application. I have looked around and I have seen many people with the same problem and no solution.

So I wanted to see if anyone has figured out how to change the background of the `ExpandBar`.

When you try to do `setBackground(color)`, it changed the backgrounds color, but completely removes all the gradients and rounded edges of the expandItems. I think you might have to paint stuff, but I am not sure how.

I have included a photo to show what it looks like with default backgrounds and then when I call

```
expandBar.setBackground(color);
```

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7Bp7DTfaivuaEtNcGo0NThaaU0

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Changing OS widget background is just a hint in SWT API. It might be or might not be honored based on the OS. Pls Look at `Control.setBackground (Color color)` documentation.

Comment: The main problem is that when I set the background it affects the foreground and the background image. I just wanted to see if anyone had written code to completely customize the whole expandbar